# Do gathering skills Stack?

Tags: etrian-odyssey-untold

I'm playing Story Mode, in it Myself and Raquna have the Mine skill and i am wondering if the effects stack since or if it's only beneficial to have 1 character specialize in a gathering skill.

NOTE: i do not want to know if/when characters leave the party as if the skills do not stack i can assume the party will change

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If you're playing story mode, the party will never change. Gathering skills do stack, but putting gathering skills on the main party is a waste of skill points on expert, as you can gather once per day anyway without any skills in Untold. If you're playing on any of the easier difficulties though, feel free to put points into gathering skills, the extra money and better equipment may help. You can gather anything and everything without any gathering skills, but it is faster with gathering skills, as you can get more materials per trip/day.